# The distribution of STD/MAD for a Student-t

Tags: probability, distributions, estimation, t-distribution

Where $X \sim a$ symmetric Student-t Distribution $t_\alpha$, with power law tail $\alpha>2$, looking for the distribution of

$$ \frac{\sqrt{ \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 }}{\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|}, $$

in order to estimate the properties of the statistic STD/MAD for a sample size $n$.

The problem is that both measures, MAD and STD will be correlated for a given draw, so we cannot work with two different distributions.

Comment: This statistic is the inverse of Geary's 1935 $a$ statistic for testing normality against symmetric alternatives (with mean taken at zero). He considered its distribution, primarily in the normal case, e.g. [see his 1947 paper](http://webspace.ship.edu/pgmarr/Geo441/Readings/Geary%201947%20-%20Testing%20for%20Normality.pdf) where he considers; it may be worth considering using his statistic and approach.